# If $S=(s_1,s_2,\ldots)$ is defined by $s_ i=\max\{j\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}|2^j\text{ divides }i\}$, then no subsequence of $S$ can appear twice in a row.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, parity

> Let $S = (s_1, s_2, s_3, \ldots)$ be an infinite sequence where $$s_ i = \max\big\{j \in \mathbb{N}  \cup \{0\} \big|2^j\text{ divides }i\big\}\,.$$ I need to prove (i'm quite sure it's true) that  a subsequence $S'=x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k$ of $S$ can't appear twice in a row for any $k$, meaning that  $S'S'$ can't appear in the sequence $S$

I thought maybe it has something with the even numbers and odd numbers in the sequence. I tried to prove it using induction, but failed to prove anything in the induction step.I'm also thinking it was a naive try.

Comment: If $k=2^st$, where $s\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ and $t$ is an odd integer, then show that a subsequence of $S$ consisting of $2k$ consecutive entries has exactly $t$ elements that are greater than $s$.  Since $t$ is odd, what can you conclude from this observation?

Comment: @Batominovski if I know that it's simple: if the first $k$ elements in the subsequence are the same as the last $k$ elements, then each one of them will have $t/2$ elements that are greater than s. Right? What I don't understand is how to prove what you told me to show. Can you please guide me or show it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note that $2k$ is divisible by $2^{s+1}$.  Now observe the following: for $2^{s+1}$ consecutive integers, exactly one of them is divisible by $2^{s+1}$.

Comment: I think I got it (will update if not). Thank you.